# How to sort List<Map<String, Object>> in java8 with .stream()?

Tags: java

I have a List like this

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("quantity", Math.random());
        map.put("price", Math.random());
        list.add(map);
    }
```

How can I sort by price?

I hope it is use java8 stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a stream to sort:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> (Double)m.get("price")));
```

Comment: This answer gave me idea about how to retrieve value with keyname and sort the list. My use case demanded to use sorting based on fromdate and then todate and I used thenComparator for it. But this answer gave me a good break through.

Comment: @shmosel This is a really helpful answer. One question though how can we sort the same list in descending order

Comment: @user8765332 You can negate the amount or call `.reversed()` on the comparator.